# Increase rpool size on Solaris 11.3 ESXi Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, zpool, solaris-11

I'm trying to run updates on my **Solaris 11.3** server but I am unable to because there isn't enough space on my **rpool**. I've tried deleting log files and other useless stuff but it's not enough. Therefore, I need to extend the size of rpool.

My Solaris server is an **ESXi virtual machine** and currently has *one hard drive* assigned to it that's *100gb*. The server has two ZFS pools - rpool and one called data which we used for solaris updates (the problem server is our repo server). I've never done any kind of systems administration on a solaris server so this is kind of new. I also don't have access to vSphere - I have to contact somebody from support and instruct them on what I need then I can handle everything from CLI.

What would be the best course of action - increase the size of the existing hard drive, add a second hard drive? Any simple and to the point instructions would be greatly appreciated. I've tried reading over the Oracle docs but I think those instructions are for ***bare metal installations, not virtual environments***.

Comment: Post your `df -h` output.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, the server in question is on a locked down network and I don't have a cell phone to take a photo of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second drive that is larger, resilver on it, drop the small disk.

A simple way to do this is documented at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54801/ghzvz.html#scrolltoc in the Oracle Documentation for Solaris 11.3

There are other ways but with this one I can just point you to the docs.

Removing unneeeded boot environment can clear a lot storage as well sometimes. Especially if there were many updates in the past.

This works with virtual environments as well as with physical ones ...

Comment: Thank you, I was told we have Oracle support so I reached out and they said the same thing essentially (add a second disk). These were the instructions they provided: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=93439023843347&parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-15177880811&id=2197231.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=10f32uupx4_154 thank you for the help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Remove unneeded files, cache and free up space?

Without having any better details, that's your best course of action; especially if you don't have vSphere access, don't know Solaris and have trepidation about a drive expansion operation.